# regression Felm: Error in chol.default(mat[ok, ok]) : 'a' must have dims > 0

Tags: r, linear-regression

I am currently trying to run a fixed effects linear regression with the following model:

```
regression1 <- felm(average_score ~ giveaway + giveaway:factor(copytype) +
                                       giveaway:winning_odds | movie_id + year_month ,
                    data = movielist)
```

However I keep getting the following error:
*

```
Error in chol.default(mat[ok, ok]) : 'a' must have dims > 0
In addition: Warning message:
In chol.default(mat, pivot = TRUE, tol = tol) :
  the matrix is either rank-deficient or indefinite
```

The movie_id is the variable that causes the error but I do not know how to fix it. It is a unique identifyer and I was told to use it as it accounts for differences between movies such as romance vs mystery etc.

the dataset looks somewhat like this:

```
> movie_id  title       average score  giveaway copytype winning_odds year month
> 259764   Romeo & juliet     4.68       0       1        NA          1689-04
> 58697    James Bond         3.98       1       3        0.0036      2008-07
```

I tried to solve it by identiying where it came from and concluded it came from the movie_id variable, but unsure what it caused. I removed all the NA's and tried several solutions proposed online but it doesn't seem to work. Every row has an ID and (as expected) recoding the id into a factor also did not work..

Here is a reproducable example using dput():

> structure(list(c(49207064L, 40610763L, 18342451L, 24611562L,
> 18112455L, 37954232L, 41559097L, 32982694L, 30078050L, 26205520L,
> 45212165L, 25257581L, 39838159L, 28146924L, 48977227L, 28152663L,
> 19358557L, 20295281L, 40011514L, 12407923L, 13631830L, 22889883L,
> 1538505L, 37823518L, 13614942L, 48919775L, 14553840L, 6098580L,
> 17868537L, 11787536L), c("True Blue Cowboy", "SEVENTEEN: 17",
> "Translations from Bark Beetle: Poems", "Hard Beat (Driven, #7)",
> "House of Steel (Unraveled, #1)", "Rx", "Ethic 2", "Black History In
> Its Own Words",  "My Hope Next Door", "The Dragon's Egg", "The Memory
> Thief",  "The Big Old House And The Scary Storm", "Hong Kong Noir",
> "The Messengers: Discovered",  "Trouble", "Altered", "What Goes on
> Tour", "About Matters of the Hurt: Love Stories - Round the Clock",
> "The 21: A Journey Into the Land of Coptic Martyrs", "These Arms of
> Mine",  "The Breast of Everything", "The Ghost Network",
> "Unconventional Flying Objects: A Scientific Analysis: A Scientific
> Analysis",  "The Way of Life: Experiencing the Culture of Heaven on
> Earth",  "Land", "Alan Cumming: Legal Immigrant", "I Could Pee On
> This: And Other Poems By Cats",  "Heaven is Small", "The Wayang at
> Eight Milestone: Stories & Essays",  "Turning Point"), c(2020L, 2018L,
> 2014L, 2015L, 2013L, 2018L,  2018L, 2017L, 2016L, 2015L, 2019L, 2014L,
> 2018L, 2016L, 2019L,  2016L, 2014L, 2013L, 2019L, 2012L, 2012L, 2015L,
> 1995L, 2018L,  2012L, 2019L, 2012L, 2009L, 2013L, 2011L), c(2L, 9L,
> 4L, 11L,  6L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 9L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 12L, 5L, 11L, 2L, 2L, 12L,
> 2L, 1L, 4L, 5L, 12L, 9L, 4L, 11L, 8L, 4L, 10L, 10L), c(4.27,
> 3.71, 4.09, 4.19, 3.48, 3.81, 4.74, 4.16, 4.36, 3.98, 4.08, 5,
> 3.8, 4.34, 3.72, 3.75, 3.62, 3.91, 4.09, 4.06, 4.67, 3.1, 4.04,
> 4.63, 3.89, 4.24, 3.96, 3.31, 3.97, 3.95), c(385L, 17L, 22L,  3887L, 132L, 817L, 1792L, 454L, 1139L, 1113L, 1154L, 4L, 127L,  108L, 446L,
> 49L, 1680L, 11L, 113L, 88L, 12L, 1359L, 34L, 224L,  2490L, 226L,
> 8182L, 140L, 30L, 51L), c(52L, 0L, 4L, 397L, 27L,  120L, 246L, 103L,
> 190L, 82L, 213L, 1L, 27L, 35L, 57L, 39L, 174L,  6L, 50L, 23L, 6L,
> 273L, 7L, 23L, 246L, 26L, 1243L, 31L, 3L, 17L ), c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L,  2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,
> 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L ), c("2020-2", "2018-9", "2014-04",
> "2015-11", "2013-06", "2018-09",  "2018-10", "2017-02", "2016-9",
> "2015-8", "2019-4", "2014-10",  "2018-12", "2016-05", "2019-11",
> "2016-02", "2014-2", "2013-12",  "2019-02", "2012-01", "2012-04",
> "2015-05", "1995-12", "2018-9",  "2012-4", "2019-11", "2012-08",
> "2009-4", "2013-10", "2011-10" ), c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L,
> 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L,  0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,
> 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L ), c(0, 0, 0.0173913043478261, 0.0114285714285714,
> 0.00134952766531714,
> 0.00715307582260372, 0, 0.00154798761609907, 0, 0, 0, 0.333333333333333,  0, 0.00201207243460765, 0, 0.00590841949778434, 0, 0.00284900284900285,
> 0.0109170305676856, 0.00323624595469256, 0.00627615062761506,
> 0.000873362445414847, 0.00354609929078014, 0, 0, 0, 0.00109289617486339,  0, 0.00148809523809524, 0.08110300081103)), row.names = c(NA,
> -30L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x00000191ca3c32b0>, names = c("movie_id",  "title",
> "publication_year", "publication_month", "average_rating",
> "ratings_count", "text_reviews_count", "copytype", "year_month",
> "giveaway", "winning_odds"))

Comment: Instead of providing a table, can you make your post [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and provide your data using `dput(movielist)`?

Comment: @jrcalabrese I added a piece of the dataset, hopefully it helps :)